# What does "GR" mean on a pcb

Tags: power-supply, pcb, components

I have two components on a power supply board labelled GR1 and GR2 each having 4 pins. Are these opto isolators?

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Comment: Post a picture.

Comment: Please show a (decent quality) photo of the circuit and these components. That makes it easier to see what you have there.

Comment: Is it a german board? A 4-pin part labeled GR could be a "Gleichrichter", which is a rectifier.

Comment: I did try adding pictures originally but it kept saying a problem occurred, I have since uploaded to imgur.

Comment: Yes, these are two rectifiers, as suggested above.

Comment: It seems this isn't the answer, but when I saw the question I thought it might be "germanium rectifier", which you might see on old boards. (germanium diodes have lower forward voltage than silicon p-n diodes, so they may be specified separately on a board, but their role is replaced today by silicon schottky diodes, which have a similarly low forward voltage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are they are 4-diode rectifier bridges. They might have the symbols ~ for AC input, and the symbols + and - for DC output.

EDIT: Now that you have uploaded the picture, they're definitely 4-diode rectifier bridges. The datasheet for VM28 says they are rated for 1A curent and 200V peak reverse voltage. Most of us could have guessed it was a 1A rectifier, based on the chip size and the lack of any additional cooling provision.

Answer (score 3):

Enlarging and rotating the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz54Z.jpg), we can see the component's part number:

[image: VM28 rectifiers]

They are (obsolete?) **VM28** bridge rectifiers, probably manufactured in week 27 of 1988 (hence the "8827" seen on them).

The specific manufacturer logo isn't one I recognise. However as an example, the [Microsemi-manufactured](https://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/vm28/2424617885719649914/) VM28 bridge rectifiers are rated at 200 Vpk, 1A and that is likely to apply here too ("second sources" should meet the main specifications).

Comment: The transformer looks like a german product. Sek. is the abbreviation of "sekundär", for secondary sec. would be used. In german GR is for Gleichrichter which means rectifier.

Comment: The transformer is actually Swiss (thanks, Google!).